# angular2 webpack import custom javascript

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack-2

I have a javascript file with custom code written and I want to import and call the function in .js file in my angular2 webpack project's component. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to supply a bit more information, as your question is quite broad.

Comment: I have a component "a.component.ts" and a java script file "b.js" with createGraph() as function.

My requirement is to call createGraph() from "b.js" in "a.component.ts"

Using systemJs approach I used to include "b.js" in index.html file and declare its function as "declare function createGraph():void;" in "a.component.ts".

Now I converted my project to angular2 webpack and not sure how to call createGraph() from "b.js" in "a.component.ts"

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.